# Um SELECT que puxe linhas de uma coluna (string;string)

Tags: php, sql

Bom galera preciso de um SELECT que retorne todas as linhas que contém o nome "maria", tenho numa coluna os valores e quero um select que me mostre todas as linhas que possuem a palavra "maria" naquela coluna.

Exemplo, em determinada coluna possuo os valores:

1) (joana;carla;josefa)

2) (gabriela;maria;julia)

3) (maria;carol;jaqueline)

O SELECT precisa me retornar as linhas de **2** e **3** que possuem "maria"

Preciso para fazer uma filtragem em php e listar determinado dado dessas linhas

Comment: O que você já tentou fazer ?

Comment: select * from cms_news where author like "%maria%", só não é eficaz porque mostra todos que tem o trecho maria no nome

Comment: E não é isso que você está precisando ? Pois é o que você esta falando na pergunta! Veja esse exemplo que fiz no [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0c66fe/1)

Comment: Vou sinalizar para fechar a perguntar, pois se é apenas isso, você esta fazendo certo, a não ser que está encontrando algum problema, sendo assim [edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/251863/edit) sua pergunta e faça uma melhor descrição de sua dúvida ou problema. Dúvidas leia [O que significa se uma pergunta está "fechada" ou "pendente"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

Comment: Já resolvido, eu estava errando mesmo. Obrigado pela força

Comment: Coloca a resolução homi

Comment: Olá @GiovanyHenrique, eu tenho um jeito que é possivel a pesquisa coluna a coluna, porém em SQL SERVER, qual o BD que você está utilizando?

Comment: O jeito que fiz foi colocar um caracter antes e depois do nome da pessoa, assim a sql da postagem saia correta, exemplo, em vez de por "maria" coloquei ";maria;", e quando fui exibir tirei os ";", já que apenas eu vou ver que tem os ponto-vírgulas, então tudo bem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que entendi você tem um campo varchar e precisa encontrar nele, todos os nome que contenham um determinado valor, você pode usar os comando `like` mais `%`.

O operador `LIKE` é usado em uma cláusula `WHERE` para procurar um padrão especificado em uma coluna. Exemplo:

```
SELECT column1, column2, ...
FROM table_name
WHERE columnN LIKE pattern;
```

Outra possibilidade a ser explorada é o uso do operador `_`. Este definindo um caracter qualquer, por exemplo:

```
WHERE CustomerName LIKE '_r%'
```

Procurará qualquer palavra com o r na segunda posição. Podendo ser usado de diversas formar que você pode ver mais [aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp).

Tendo dito todos estes conceitos, a maneira de solucionar seu problema seria um `select` com `like` simples:

```
select * from TABELA where CAMPO LIKE '%maria%'
```